# Why are the Left and Right Riemann sums for $\int_a^b f(x)\ dx$ equal?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, riemann-integration

- For finding the area under $\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) = x$ from $a$ to $b$,

  - if a right Riemann sum is
    $$
    \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{b - a}{n}
    \sum_{i = 1}^{n}
    \operatorname{f}\left(a + i\,\frac{b - a}{n}\right)
    \quad\mbox{and}
    $$
  - if a left Riemann sum is
    $$
    \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b - a}{n}
    \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1}
    \operatorname{f}\left(a + i\,\frac{b - a}{n}\right),
    $$

then why would they be equal $?$.

Is it because the limits as $n\to \infty$ make it so the summation's indexing doesn't matter when it moves down by one $?$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the difference between the two sums is  $$(b-a)(f(b)-f(a))/n$$ which approaches zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Thus the two limits are the same provided that they exist.

Comment: I think I got that now since it becomes very clear when you write out the first two and last two of the Left and Right sums. almost everything except the outermost terms

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two terms is

$$d_n=\frac{b-a}{n}(f(b)-f(a)).$$

As a function Riemann integrable is bounded, let say $\vert f(x) \vert \le M$ for $x \in [a,b]$, we get

$$\vert d_n \vert \le \frac{2M(b-a)}{n}$$ and

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d_n=0.$$

Indeed the two sums are converging to the Riemann integral $\int_a^b f$.